# Resizing Powerpoint Viewer within WPF application using WinAPI

Tags: c#, wpf, winapi, powerpoint, viewer

I am trying to embed PowerPoint Viewer 2007 in my WPF application. I managed to use a Process to start up the viewer with a file specified and put it in my application window with SetParent and such WinAPI commands. But the slideshow in my application window is always chopped off partially because my application window is not full screen and unfortunately PowerPoint Viewer always starts up fullscreen. Any idea how I can resize the slideshow so that it appears nicely in my window?

So far, here is my code.

```
Process proc = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(){ FileName = "C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\Office12\\PptView.exe", Arguments="/S" + "\"" + "C:\\Test.ppt" + "\"", WindowStyle=ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized});

System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
SetParent(proc.MainWindowHandle, myWindowHandle);
SendMessage(proc.MainWindowHandle, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MAXIMIZE, 0);
SetWindowPos(proc.MainWindowHandle, (IntPtr)0, 0, 0, 800, 600, SWP_FRAMECHANGED);
InvalidateRect(myWindowHandle, IntPtr.Zero, false);
```

Hope someone can help. Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try MoveWindow(proc.MainWindowHandle, 0, 0, 800, 600, true);? I had issues doing something similar to this, but with Word. SetWindowPos didn't position the screen where I wanted it.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I tried that approach before, the position did move, but same issue with the size. The child window (the powerpoint viewer) resized to 800x600, but the slideshow within the viewer din resize accordingly. As a result, the slideshow was chopped off from the right and bottom. I would love to post an image of what I mean if I can, but I'm a new user. :P So hope you understand what I mean. :)

Comment: @bbdaffy I'm trying also to view PPT files in my WPF application. Did you get a solution to your problem? Thanks